# Compare shape of types at compile time in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to take two types and make sure they have the same shape? For example:

```
// foo.json
{
    "key1": {
        "key2": "foo"
    }
}

// bar.json
{
    "key1": { 
        "key2": "bar"
    }
}

// baz.json
{
    "key1": {
        "otherkey": ""
    }
}

// main.ts

import foo from "./foo.json";
import bar from "./bar.json";
import baz from "./baz.json";

type FooType = typeof foo;
type BarType = typeof bar;
type BazType = typeof baz;

// FooType === BarType --> true
// FooType === BazType --> false
```

It would be possible to do something like

```
const f: FooType = {} as BarType;
const b: BarType = {} as FooType;
```

But this is rather ugly and doesn't really describe what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing, if your json files are data, i.e. not known at compilation time, then there's nothing you can do - TypeScript types only exist at compile time.

If you want to compare two types, you could write something like this:

```
type Equal<A, B> = A extends B ? B extends A ? true : false : false;
```

And then somewhere:

```
interface A {
    s: string;
    n: number;
}

interface B {
    s: string;
}

const EQUAL_A_B: Equal<A, B> = true;
```

Right now this won't compile, with error `Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'.` because the two types are not equal.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I had attempted something similar with a generic function like `const ensureSameShape = <T1 extends T2, T2 extends T1>() => {}` but it (kind of expectedly) didn't work as it was a circular constraint. Hadn't though of this way. Thanks!